# How do i animate this design with a walk cycle for the legs and having the orange part act as a costume?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

[image: I am trying to rig this model. It's an orange with legs, but i want the orange to act like a costume, not part of the legs when i rig i. However when I test in pose mode for the model to work, the model bends with the legs, instead of just staying still. How do i rig the orange part with the armature for the animation, but not have it bend as if it's a part of the body? This is what the design looks like for an idea of what i am trying to do v]

I am trying to rig this model. It's an orange with legs, but i want the orange to act like a costume, not part of the legs when i rig i. However when I test in pose mode for the model to work, the model bends with the legs, instead of just staying still. How do i rig the orange part with the armature for the animation, but not have it bend as if it's a part of the body? This is what the design looks like for an idea of what i am trying to do v

Comment: Weight painting is likely the answer. You will want the legs to have some influence over the costume near its entrance, but not much influence, so that the costume will still move a little bit when the legs move. Probably no bones should have influence over the costume except the spine, and the thighs.

Comment: Are you using bone envelopes in the armature modifier?